# Gravar dados do usuário na sessão após o login

Tags: php, pdo

Na tela de login faço a consulta para liberar o acesso ao sistema, depois disso gostaria de fazer uma consulta completa dos dados desse usuário e gravar na SESSION.

```
    <?php
    // inclui o arquivo de inicialização
    require 'init.php';

    // resgata variáveis do formulário
    $email = isset( $_POST[ 'email' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'email' ] : '';
    $telefone = isset( $_POST[ 'telefone' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'telefone' ] : '';
    if ( empty( $email ) || empty( $telefone ) ) {
      echo "Informe Email e Senha corretamente.";
      exit;
    }

    // cria o hash da senha
    $telefoneHash = make_hash( $telefone );

    $PDO = db_connect();
    $sql = "SELECT id, name AND email FROM users WHERE email = :email AND telefone = :telefone ";
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':email', $email );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':telefone', $telefoneHash );
    $stmt->execute();
    $users = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    if ( count( $users ) <= 0 ) {
      echo "Email ou Senha incorretos";
      exit;
    }

    // pega o primeiro usuário
    $user = $users[ 0 ];
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[ 'logged_in' ] = true;
    $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] = $user[ 'id' ];
    $_SESSION[ 'user_name' ] = $user[ 'name' ];

    //AQUI É QUE PRECISO PREENCHER
    //$_SESSION['user_endereco'] =  $variavelbanco;
    //$_SESSION['user_numero'] =  $variavel2banco;
    ?>
```

Comment: Se eu entendi bem se quer gravar os dados da sua tabela numa session? se for isso porque?

Comment: Isso mesmo, na realidade acho que vou mudar de session para localStorage,  é que já tem alguns dados lá como o nome do usuário, o que não entendo é sobre a consulta e colocar os dados em variáveis.
Pesquisei bastante mas não entendo nada de conexão com o banco, não sai nada.

Comment: Então se precisa parar e começar do zero (é uma dica não me leve a mau) porque localStorage já é outra coisa ... !!!!

Comment: Você pode usar json_encode e depois salvar, tanto na session, quanto em LocalStorage. Ps.: A depender do objetivo, não é a melhor opção.

Comment: Estou usando ele, poucas informações do usuário que estão session, o carrinho de comprar e outras informações estão no localStorage.

Comment: Sim, meu problema está mais na parte em trazer os dados do banco e passa-los para variáveis

Comment: Essas informações (que você quer adicionar às sessões endereço e numero) estão na tabela users?

Comment: Sim, preciso obter essas informações:
`name`
 `email`
 `telefone` 
 `endereco` 
 `numero` 
 `bairro` 
 `cidade`

Comment: @HugoNascimento utilize o "@" para sinalizar alguém. Assim, o comentário aparece no inbox da pessoa que você está conversando. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você altera seu select:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, email, telefone, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade FROM users WHERE email = :email AND telefone = :telefone ";
```

Depois você preenche:

```
    $user = $users[ 0 ];
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[ 'logged_in' ] = true;
    $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] = $user[ 'id' ];
    $_SESSION[ 'user_name' ] = $user[ 'name' ];

    //AQUI É QUE PRECISO PREENCHER
    $_SESSION['user_endereco'] =  $user[ 'endereco' ]." ".$user[ 'numero' ]." - ".$user[ 'bairro' ]." - ".$user[ 'cidade' ];
    $_SESSION['user_numero'] =  $user[ 'telefone' ];
```